# Nginx redirect if 404 and request contain certin words

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I need to redirect if the page doesn't exist ( 404)

redirect must be smart
if URL contains word "test" redirect 301 to a new_page, else throw 404

```
# define error page
error_page 404 = @notfound;

# error page location redirect 302
location @notfound {
    
   if ($request_uri = "test"){
        return 301 /new_page ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set custom 404 error page on nginx based on locale through url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387522/set-custom-404-error-page-on-nginx-based-on-locale-through-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
map $request_uri $error404 {
    ~test    error404_redirect;
    default  error404_notfound;
}

server {
    ...
    error_page 404 = @$error404;
    location @error404_notfound {
        return 404;
    }
    location @error404_redirect {
        return 301 /new_page;
    }
}
```